# Sample event system code for Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Right now we are using Tridion 5.3. For number of publications we have event system implemented like sending some mail notification if component is localized, or sending a mail notification when particular activity is completed in workflow process etc.

Our current event system is implementation in Visual Basic 6.0, now when we have to rewrite our code we have to use .NET for the same.

My question is where I can get some sample code for beginners or documentation how event system can be implemented in Tridion 2011 SP1.

Answer (score 12):

These are the top three links when I google for Tridion 2011 event systems:

- http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/sdltridion2011eventsystem.aspx
- http://www.julianwraith.com/2011/02/event-systems-in-sdl-tridion-2011/
- http://www.curlette.com/?p=90

Each of them is a decent introduction to writing event handlers for Tridion 2011, which in itself is a lot clear/less involved than writing an event system for previous Tridion versions.

If you are having a concrete problem with your Tridion 2011 event handler, I suggest posting the code and describing the problem.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Frank's excellent suggestions, there is also a [sample event handler](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_204AB86C028A4099A2DAFD31C9901ED8) and [full documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_15E64E07A828429A8AE60D37ED8E474E) available in the [online docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/) (Username/Password required).